# Linux bash executables behave differently depending on whether I am activating from the command line or with os.system('')

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been attempting to execute a certain CLI from within python and store the output for later use within the same script. I suspect this question has a simple answer, but if one wishes to go through the entire pipeline, here is the tool in question.

wget http://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/Releases/current/RNAstructureForLinux.tgz

tar xvf as usual, go inside the resulting directory and execute 'make all', the executables I use in the bash script are within the 'exe' directory.

I attempted to execute the commands with os.system(), but with little luck. The CLI I am using; however, seems to be running. The function which I have set to execute the os.system() commands contains the following block.

```
txt = open('home/spectre/tools/RNAstructure/exe/RNAStructure_nucleic_acid.txt',"w")
txt.write('AAGGCTGTCCAGGCGCAATGTGGTGGCTGCTTCTCTGGGGAGTCCTCCAGGCTTGCCCAACCCGGGGCTCCGTCCTCTTGGCCCAAGAGCTACCCCAGCAGCTGACATCCCCCGGGTACCCAGAGCCGTATGGCAAAGGCCAAGAGAGCAGCACGGACATCAAGGCTCCAGAGGGCTTTGCTGTGAGGCTCGTCTTCCAGGACTTCGACCTGGAGCCGTCCCAGGACTGTGCAGGGGACTCTGTCACAGTGAGCTGGGGATGGGGGGGGTCCCGCCAGGACTGTGGCCAGGGAGATTCCCGGGGTTGTGGGAAGTGGCGGTGCCCTGAATCCCCCATCTGGAGGAGGGATGAAT')

os.system(' cd ~/tools/RNAstructure/exe ; ./python_RNA_structure.sh')

nucleotides, structure, MFE = 

RNAStructure_from_file('home/spectre/tools/RNAstructure/exe/RNAStructure_bracket_output.txt')
```

The executable *.sh file contains this.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/tools/RNAstructure/exe

./Fold RNAStructure_nucleic_acid.txt RNAStructure_nucleic_acid_output.txt

./ct2dot RNAStructure_nucleic_acid_output.txt -1 RNAStructure_bracket_output.txt
```

If I execute the bash script from the command line the output should look a little like this

```
Initializing nucleic acids...
Using auto-detected DATAPATH: "../data_tables" (set DATAPATH to avoid this warning).
done.
98% \[==================================================\] \\                     done.
Writing output ct file...done.
Single strand folding complete.
Converting CT file...
Using auto-detected DATAPATH: "../data_tables" (set DATAPATH to avoid this warning).
CT file conversion complete.
```

If I execute the bash script form the python file.

```
Initializing nucleic acids...
Using auto-detected DATAPATH: "../data_tables" (set DATAPATH to avoid this warning).

Error reading sequence.  The file did not contain any nucleotides.

Single strand folding complete with errors.
Converting CT file...
Using auto-detected DATAPATH: "../data_tables" (set DATAPATH to avoid this warning).
CT file conversion complete.
```

It looks an awful lot like my CLI can find the files it needs inside the terminal, but not outside of it. I haven't experimented with any parameters like trying absolute paths, but I understood by using os.system() I could execute a bash script, but it is not clear to me why this is changing how that script behaves.

What I've done to resolve the problem:

reopening the file seems to resolve the problem, but I am still working out why.

Comment: Note that `system()` uses sh, not bash.

Comment: Also, note that a `~` in an `open()` call doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : While it is correct that the command passed to `system` is not executed by bash, `sh` would just do the `cd` and then invoke the shell script, which is said to be executable, and also contains a #! line for `bash`.

Comment: Since the error message comes from either `Fold` or  `ct2dot` and you don't show us anything about these programs, I can't say what's going wrong.

Comment: As CharlesDuffy mentioned, the `~` in your open statement looks odd. I'm not that proficient in Python, but I think that you would have to use [`expanduser`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-expanduser-method/) if you want the tilde to be converted to your home directory.

Comment: @mashuptwice that's not necessarily true. The thing that distinguishes environment variables from shell variables is that they're inherited by subprocesses, so if you start your Python script from a shell, it and anything it runs gets that shell's environment variables (`export` is what transforms a shell variable into an environment variable).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the clarification, I love to learn something new!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edited out the '~', thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @AlexPlastow, note that the new path looks to be intended to be absolute, but not having a `/` at the front makes it relative.

Comment: You didn't close the file, so most or all of that data was still in a buffer rather than actually being written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to resolve when I reopen the file within the python script like so:

```
txt = open('home/spectre/tools/RNAstructure/exe/RNAStructure_nucleic_acid.txt',"w")

txt.write('AAGGCTGTCCAGGCGCAATGTGGTGGCTGCTTCTCTGGGGAGTCCTCCAGGCTTGCCCAACCCGGGGCTCCGTCCTCTTGGCCCAAGAGCTACCCCAGCAGCTGACATCCCCCGGGTACCCAGAGCCGTATGGCAAAGGCCAAGAGAGCAGCACGGACATCAAGGCTCCAGAGGGCTTTGCTGTGAGGCTCGTCTTCCAGGACTTCGACCTGGAGCCGTCCCAGGACTGTGCAGGGGACTCTGTCACAGTGAGCTGGGGATGGGGGGGGTCCCGCCAGGACTGTGGCCAGGGAGATTCCCGGGGTTGTGGGAAGTGGCGGTGCCCTGAATCCCCCATCTGGAGGAGGGATGAAT')

txt = open('home/spectre/tools/RNAstructure/exe/RNAStructure_nucleic_acid.txt')

os.system(' cd ~/tools/RNAstructure/exe ; ./python_RNA_structure.sh')

nucleotides, structure, MFE = 

RNAStructure_from_file('home/spectre/tools/RNAstructure/exe/RNAStructure_bracket_output.txt')
```

I am not sure why this resolves the problem, I found this solution serendipitously. I'll update the answer when I figure out why, unless someone wants to beat me to it. It's magic to me for now.

It seems that after opening the file, RNAStructure_nucleic_acid.txt, and assigning it to the txt variable for writing, I need to reopen it after writing is complete. Otherwise the file is blank when I try printing it's output within the program, but after the program finishes executing, the file contains the correct text.

Comment: File objects need to be closed to flush your writes to disk. Calling `txt.close()` after your last write should do the trick. What's happening here is that the file is being implicitly closed when the `txt` variable is assigned to a new file object in the second `open` statement.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=close%20file#io.IOBase.close